# Error with min and max values random generator java

Tags: java, eclipse

When I enter the minimum and maximum value it shows a value outside these bounderies. Why is this? For example:

```
Enter minimum value: 20
Enter maximum value: 40
Your number is: 50
```

There is other code as well, but that all works fine. Here is the method below which does not work:

```
public void randomNumberMinMax(){

    int min;
    int max;

    System.out.print("Enter minimum value: ");
    min = myScan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter maximum value: ");
    max = myScan.nextInt();

    int i = (int)(Math.random() * max) + min;
    System.out.println("Your number is: " + i);
    if (i < min || i >= max);
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomNumberGenerator generator = new RandomNumberGenerator();
    generator.randomNumberMinMax();
```

Comment: Look carefully at what you are doing. You generate a random integer under 40 (say 30 gets chosen), then you add 20 to it. You will get 50.

Comment: You might try: int i = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; but won't work with minus numbers probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently generating random with incorrect bounds. You have code like

```
int i = (int)(Math.random() * max) + min;
```

Let say `Math.random` generate a value like `0.9939045240919046`, then you are multiplying this value by `40` , which becomes `39,756180964` and then you are adding `20` to it , which gives you

```
39,756180964 + 20 = 59,756180964
```

You can correct it by either using

```
int i = new Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min // this will generate number b/w min and max inclusive
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to replace line:

int i = (int)(Math.random() * max) + min;

with

int i = (new Random()).nextInt(max-min) + min;

Answer (score -1):

Using Random Generator like one [here RandomUtil class](https://github.com/exp2Tapavicki/RandomDataGenerator/blob/master/RandomDataGenerator/src/java/com/rdg/util/RandomUtil.java) you can make random numbers between some values and much more.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int minRange = -20;
    int maxRange = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int number = getRandomPrimitiveInt(minRange, maxRange);
        System.out.println(number);
    }

}

public static int getRandomPrimitiveInt(int minRange, int maxRange) {
    if (minRange < 0){
        int value = (int) ((Math.random() * (maxRange + Const.ONE)) + Const.ZERO);
        if (getPositiveOrNegative()){
            return value;
        } else {
            return Math.negateExact(value);
        }
    } else {
        return (int) ((Math.random() * (maxRange - minRange + Const.ONE)) + minRange);
    }
}

private static boolean getPositiveOrNegative() {
    int lRandomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * Const.THREE);
    if (lRandomNumber % Const.TWO == Const.ZERO) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry I just wanted to answer on topic "Error with min and max values random generator java". Maybe show solution for some cases. I'll edit my post.